# mysql datatype for telephone number and address

Tags: mysql, types, phone-number, street-address

I want to input telephone number in a form, including country code, extension

```
create table if not exists employee(    `   
      country_code_tel   int(11),
      tel_number         int(10),
      extension          int(10),
      mobile             bigint(20)
);
```

If tel_number is larger than 15 bit, which datatype can I use, I'd better use `Bigint(20)`?

```
create table address(
      address           varchar(255),  
      city              varchar(255),
      country           varchar(255),
      post_code         int(11)
);
```

For example, if I have a country code for Canada I can use +2 or 002. Which is better for processing?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Well, personally I do not use numeric datatype to store phone numbers or related info.

How do you store a number say 001234567? It'll end up as 1234567, losing the leading zeros.

Of course you can always left-pad it up, but that's provided you know exactly how many digits the number should be.

This doesn't answer your entire post,
Just my 2 cents

Comment: @garcon: Honestly speaking, the other guys here gave more holistic views. Mine is just one of many scenarios which 'void' the use of numeric type for phone numbers. :P

Comment: http://img.thedailywtf.com/images/12/q2/err6/pic3.png pretty much proves everything

Answer (score 51):

Actually you can use a varchar for a telephone number. You do not need an int because you are not going to perform arithmetic on the numbers.

Comment: @Vincent, but if i want to use authenticate the format of numbers, i think i have to use int. Actually it's the first time i make a "real application", So I want to get your suggestions from real projects.

Comment: @garcon1986: The validation - (not 'authentication')  - has to be done on your application prior to comitting to the databases. You could prefer writing an SQL trigger with a valitation PL procedure to live inside the database - this will be harder, but is the way to go if your DB data willbe acessed by front-end apps written in different programing languages by different people -  , but you should not rely onthe database datatype for validation

Comment: @garcon1986 Validation is still easier with varchar than int. Every real project that I know uses varchar rather thasn int for telephone fields. Even validation libraries expect characters.

Comment: @thanks a lot, Vincent. I'm sorry for misunderstanding the two concepts firstly. And I'll try to use "varchar" type in telephone numbers with validation.

Comment: @garcon1986 It is no problem at all. No need to apologize...that is why this site exists

Comment: I can't speak for mysql specifically, but you should be able to have a check constraint that ensures a varchar only contains digits

Answer (score 32):

Store them as two fields for phone numbers - a "number" and a "mask" as `TinyText` types *which do not need more than 255 items*.

Before we store the files we parse the phone number to get the formatting that has been used and that creates the mask, we then store the number a digits only e.g.

Input:  `(0123) 456 7890`
Number: `01234567890`
Mask:   `(nnnn)_nnn_nnnn`

Theoretically this allows us to perform comparison searches on the Number field such as getting all phone numbers that begin with a specific area code, without having to worry how it was input by the users

Comment: @Dan Kelly, Thanks , you have provided me with another method.  cool!

Comment: Just curious: Why TINYTEXT?

Comment: In our case we wanted to be able to store the leading 0 in the "number" field, and didn't see any scenario where the stored data would be > 255 chars.

Answer (score 26):

I usually store phone numbers as a BIGINT in E164 format.

E164 never start with a 0, with the first few digits being the country code.

```
+441234567890
+44 (0)1234 567890
01234 567890
```

etc. would be stored as `441234567890`.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer didn't get more votes -- I also chose BIGINT unsigned.  I agree that E164 never starts with 0, always starts with + which my application adds, contains only numeric digits, and most importantly it uses substantially less space than character types.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the lack of numbers beginning with 0. I was not previously aware of that. So assuming full E.164 format, a leading zero should only be part of the international dialing prefix, i.e., the dial-out code, which varies by region, and is not part of the number per se. That prefix would actually be a function of the location of the app or person using the number, not the number itself, and thus generally should not be stored. In future designs I will consider bigint as an option.

Comment: Trickier to search for all numbers within a certain country code, or country code and area code though?

Answer (score 7):

i would use a varchar for telephone numbers. that way you can also store + and (), which is sometimes seen in tel numbers (as you mentioned yourself). and you don't have to worry about using up all bits in integers.

Comment: @KON，thanks， i prefer to use varchar for telephone numbers now.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure whether it's a good idea to use integers at all. Some numbers might contain special characters (# as part of the extension for example) which you should be able to handle too. So I would suggest using varchars instead.

Comment: @nfechner, Thanks for providing the case, it's practical.

Comment: we use an 'x' here..   999 9999 x1234

Comment: It may be wise at times to store an extension separately. For example, in an automatic voice messaging application, the app must know to dial the number, wait for the call to be answered, pause, and then dial the extension. In other words, the two parts have separate meaning to the app and may require different code. In my opinion it is cleaner to handle that using two columns than using a delimiter in one column. I am not saying either way is right or wrong; it depends on the design tradeoffs at hand. I merely mean to point out that there are other ways of handling extensions.

Answer (score 4):

If storing less then 1 mil records, and high performance is not an issue go for varchar(20)/char(20) otherwise I've found that for storing even 100 milion global business phones or personal phones, int is best. Reason : smaller key -> higher read/write speed, also formatting can allow for duplicates.

1 phone in char(20) = 20 bytes vs 8 bytes `bigint` (or 10 vs 4 bytes `int` for local phones, up to 9 digits) , less entries can enter the index block => more blocks => more searches, see [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,36252,36263#msg-36263) for more info (writen for Mysql but it should be true for other Relational Databases).

Here is an example of phone tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `phoneNrs` (   
    `internationalTelNr` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'full number, no leading 00 or +, up to 19 digits, E164 format',
    `format` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ex: (+NN) NNN NNN NNN, optional',
    PRIMARY KEY (`internationalTelNr`)
    )
DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii
DEFAULT COLLATE=ascii_bin
```

or with processing/splitting before insert (2+2+4+1 = 9 bytes)

```
CREATE TABLE `phoneNrs` (   
    `countryPrefix` SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'countryCode with no leading 00 or +, up to 4 digits',
    `countyPrefix` SMALLINT unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'countyCode with no leading 0, could be missing for short number format, up to 4 digits',
    `localTelNr` int unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'local number, up to 9 digits',
    `localLeadingZeros` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'used to reconstruct leading 0, IF(localLeadingZeros>0;LPAD(localTelNr,localLeadingZeros+LENGTH(localTelNr),'0');localTelNr)',
    PRIMARY KEY (`countryPrefix`,`countyPrefix`,`localLeadingZeros`,`localTelNr`)  -- ordered for fast inserts
) 
DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii
DEFAULT COLLATE=ascii_bin
;
```

Also "the phone number is not a number", in my opinion is relative to the type of phone numbers. If we're talking of an internal mobile phoneBook, then strings are fine, as the user may wish to store [GSM Hash Codes](http://www.cellular.co.za/gsm_hash_code.htm). If storing [E164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) phones, bigint is the best option.

Answer (score 3):

Consider normalizing to [E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) format. For full international support, you'd need a VARCHAR of 15 digits.

See [Twilio's recommendation](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/how-do-i-format-phone-numbers-to-work-internationally) for more information on localization of phone numbers.

Answer (score 3):

INT(10) does not mean a 10-digit number, it means an integer with a display width of 10 digits. The maximum value for an INT in MySQL is 2147483647 (or 4294967295 if unsigned).

> You can use a BIGINT instead of INT to store it as a numeric. Using
>   BIGINT will save you 3 bytes per row over VARCHAR(10).

To Store "Country + area + number separately". You can try using a VARCHAR(20), this allows you the ability to store international phone numbers properly, should that need arise.

Answer (score 1):

varchar or text should be the best datatypes for storing mobile numbers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can just restrict your input to digits in the field using the `KeyPress` event, then upon insertion, in your `Insert Into Table` add a + to the command.

Easy fix