# database column int limit

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I limit my database column's integral input to a specific number of digits ?

```
CREATE TABLE tab (id INT <1 digit> not null, value INT <10 digits> not null);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a check constraint (SQL Server) or trigger (MySQL, doesn't support CHECK constraints)

SQL Server example:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
    id tinynot null CHECK (id BETWEEN 0 AND 9), 
    value INT not null CHECK (id BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999)
);
```

- If you only want one digit though, then use tinyint
- If you aren't storing numbers (eg "123456789 bananas") but, say, phone numbers then use a varchar type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284674/27535

Edit, you'd need a trigger in MySQL

Comment: CHECK syntax not suitable as it's for MySQL (I realise this was clarified after this answer, however just posting up for clarity)

Comment: @Simonatmso.net: that was clarified after my answer

Answer (score 0):

The short version is using `TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL` will be a more suitable data type, but it can't limit the values stored.

The longer version is that you may wish to read up on MySQL [integer data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html). You'll see that `TINYINT` is sufficient for your purpose as that is a 1-byte column that stores values from -128 to +127, or 0 to +255.

Secondly if you define it as `TINYINT(1)` then you are defining it as being a TINYINT with a display width of 1 digit.  This will not prevent values larger than 10 being stored though.  For more reading on this behaviour check [numeric type attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html).

Comment: Thank you, you know what I am doing ? I am going to have to do a real project tomorrow possibly on my own, don't anyone just ever "drop" me...Thanks. :-D

Comment: By the way, I think I will user VARCHAR(1). It's better as I don't need to read anymore anything. -:D

Comment: VARCHAR(1) uses 2 bytes of data, when CHAR(1) uses 1 byte due to VARCHAR needing 1 byte (at short lengths) to know how long the string is (VARCHAR = 1 byte per character in each individual string + 1 byte for length @ strings up to and including 255 characters long, while a char is 1 byte per character regardless of individual strings)  therefore if you KNOW every cell will have a 1-byte string i.e. single character, then use CHAR(1)