# PHPmyadmin field type

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to give the user the option to enter a phone number in a app i'm creating with android studio but what is the proper field type to put in on phpmyadmin ? E.g varchar, int, etc.

Also in my php code do I put it as string like I did for username and password or something different ?

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username,password, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss",$username, $password);
```

Comment: depends on the phone number format. If you are using purely numbers e.g. `0123456` then you can use `int` otherwise if you are using a format like `0-123-456` then `varchar` etc is needed.

Comment: I want to put purely numbers , but what if the user doesn't put purely numbers ?

Comment: You will need to use some javascript to do some client-side validation to stop them using anything but numbers. Otherwise the bind_param will fail to bind a non-int variable to a int reference (when you put `'i'` in bindparm)

Comment: Is there a way that they could use either format ?

Comment: Use strings, php will be smart enough to change the type later down the road if a user uses just numbers or you can force an int->string conversion to be safe/starts throwing errors :) but it'd be wise to enforce a common format for easier handling later on for whatever reason you might need.

Answer (score 0):

A phone number, despite containing digits, isn't a **number**. It's not a count of anything, you won't be doing math with it. I definitely think you should store it as a char (or possibly varchar, see below about extensions). There can be unexpected ramifications of trying to store a non number in a numeric data type (for instance, what happens if — against common convention — a user enters a phone number that starts with 0?). Some data types could introduce rounding errors.

You can do client-side or server-side validation to make sure the format matches how you prefer to store them in the database (for instance, as `555-123-4567` or `(555) 123-4567` or `5551234567`). Personally, I'd strip off all formatting such as dashes, spaces, and parenthesis for storage, then on display you can format it based on client setting, business purpose, or end-user preference.

If you have any chance of ever storing an extension (`555-123-4567 x890`) or a phone number from any other country, you should probably use varchar with enough characters to include all possibilities. I just happen to use USA phone numbers in my examples, but if someone from the UK wants to put their international number in my database, I need to allow enough character space for their longer number plus country code.

There's some interesting discussion (and differing opinions) at [mysql datatype for telephone number and address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846254/mysql-datatype-for-telephone-number-and-address)